# Getting the portlet position

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, position, portlet

Following on from :
[How to save portlet positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034360/how-to-save-portlet-positions)

I'd like to know how to get the new position of the portlet in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery UI's sortable plugin you can then use the plugin's serialize function to get data to send to back to your server.

Check out the sortable portlets demo page:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets